# intellisense does not work for namespace alias?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, ide

currently i'm working on a C++ project in visual studio 2008. i have long namespace as such

```
System::Drawing::Rectangle
```

and want to use alias for these like

```
namespace SDR = System::Drawing::Rectangle;
```

but intellisense does not recognize these aliases.
i'm personally not a fan of `using` directives, my personal preference is to qualify the full namespace.but also i dont like those namespaces to clog up the editor.so is there a workaround for this intellisense problem? or am i missing something? and to mention that these alias are block scoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rectangle is a type name, not a namespace name.  So you'll need to do this either this way:

```
namespace SD = System::Drawing;
SD::Rectangle rc(0, 0, 10, 20);
```

Or this way:

```
typedef System::Drawing::Rectangle SDR;
SDR rc(0, 0, 10, 20);
```

Beware of programmers that need to maintain your code some day and know where you live.

Comment: thanks for the correction and the solution. will be more careful henceforth.